I cant change the gridlines color on matplotlib, gridhelpercurvelinear
class TaylorDiagram(object):
    def __init__(self, STD ,fig=None, rect=111, label='_'):
    self.STD = STD
    tr = PolarAxes.PolarTransform()
    # Correlation labels
    rlocs = np.concatenate(((np.arange(11.0) / 10.0), [0.95, 0.99]))
    tlocs = np.arccos(rlocs) # Conversion to polar angles
    gl1 = gf.FixedLocator(tlocs) # Positions
    tf1 = gf.DictFormatter(dict(zip(tlocs, map(str, rlocs))))
    # Standard deviation axis extent
    self.smin = 0
    self.smax = 1.6 * self.STD

    gh = fa.GridHelperCurveLinear(tr,extremes=(0,(np.pi/2),self.smin,self.smax),grid_locator1=gl1,tick_formatter1=tf1)
    if fig is None:
      fig = plt.figure()
    
    rect = 111  # Replace with your actual 'rect' value
    ax = fa.FloatingSubplot(fig, rect, grid_helper=gh)
    ax = fig.add_subplot(ax)
    .
    .
    .

I cannot change the gridlines color can you help me? I couldn't change the gridline colors no matter what I did
